# OpenSolutionAsync - Field not found: 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ChangeWaves.Wave16_8' on .NET Framework 4.8 / 4.7.2

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

This code works fine on .NET 6,

but when I want to run it on .NET Framework 4.8, then that's what I receive

```
System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ChangeWaves.Wave16_8'.
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.IsTruncationEnabled(ExpanderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.PropertyExpander`1.ExpandPropertiesLeaveTypedAndEscaped(String expression, IPropertyProvider`1 properties, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUninitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.PropertyExpander`1.ExpandPropertiesLeaveEscaped(String expression, IPropertyProvider`1 properties, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUninitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.ExpandIntoStringLeaveEscaped(String expression, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ExpandPropertyUnescaped(ToolsetPropertyDefinition property, Expander`2 expander)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.EvaluateAndSetProperty(ToolsetPropertyDefinition property, PropertyDictionary`1 properties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String& toolsPath, String& binPath, Expander`2& expander)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolset(ToolsetPropertyDefinition toolsVersion, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadEachToolset(Dictionary`2 toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolsets(Dictionary`2 toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String& msBuildOverrideTasksPath, String& defaultOverrideToolsVersion)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadAllToolsets(Dictionary`2 toolsets, ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configurationReader, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.InitializeToolsetCollection(ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configReader)
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, IEnumerable`1 loggers, IEnumerable`1 remoteLoggers, ToolsetDefinitionLocations toolsetDefinitionLocations, Int32 maxNodeCount, Boolean onlyLogCriticalEvents, Boolean loadProjectsReadOnly)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.Build.ProjectBuildManager.StartBatchBuild(IDictionary`2 globalProperties) at /_/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/Build/ProjectBuildManager.cs:line 161
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectLoader.Worker.<LoadAsync>d__19.MoveNext() at /_/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildProjectLoader.Worker.cs:line 134
--- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the exception occurred  ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectLoader.<LoadSolutionInfoAsync>d__22.MoveNext() at /_/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildProjectLoader.cs:line 218
--- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the exception occurred  ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<OpenSolutionAsync>d__24.MoveNext() at /_/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs:line 204
--- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the exception occurred  ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.IO;

...
MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(pathToSln); <--- fails here
...
```

Of course I have:

[image]

Here are my other nugets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I may be missing?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add `Microsoft.Build` nuget

Comment: I had this same issue but my error was Field not found: "Microsoft.Build.Framework.Traits.ThrowOnDriveEnumeratingWildcard". This solution fixed the problem. (Although now I have other MSBuild related errors)